# MarkLogic XDMP-COMPARE -- Items not comparable: xs:QName("foaf:OnlineAccount")

Tags: xml, compare, marklogic

I need to retrieve property provenance information from auditing file.

```
declare namespace prov = "http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#";

for $i in fn:doc("/com.marklogic.smart-mastering/auditing/merge/2dc05692-a447-47d0-b366-3eb2a66351f7.xml")//prov:document
where $i//prov:type = 'assetTypeDescription'
return 
  <auditDocument>
        {($i//prov:entity, $i//prov:time)}
  </auditDocument>
```

The **xml** content is something like:

```
<prov:document xmlns:prov="http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" 
xmlns:sm="http://marklogic.com/smart-mastering/auditing#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

*********************************

  <prov:agent prov:id="http://marklogic.com/smart-mastering/auditing#user-admin">
    <prov:type xsi:type="xsd:QName" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">foaf:OnlineAccount</prov:type>
    <foaf:accountName>admin</foaf:accountName>
  </prov:agent>

*********************************
  <prov:hadMember>
   *******************************
    <prov:entity prov:id="http://marklogic.com/smart-mastering/auditing#/Asset/db3159f5-15b5-468c-a0b3-ad88d63ac5f6.jsonassetTypeDescription5d5170c3783d3e9c7beaac2a69e1392c15169f95b90b3cadd75d6fb52ea40e6083d7cb41fff12bce13145bc58ffca859b04be7f9429373733e6464ac01a1d907">
      <prov:type>assetTypeDescription</prov:type>
      <prov:label>/Asset/db3159f5-15b5-468c-a0b3-ad88d63ac5f6.json:assetTypeDescription</prov:label>
      <prov:location>/Asset/db3159f5-15b5-468c-a0b3-ad88d63ac5f6.json</prov:location>
      <prov:value>Stock</prov:value>
    </prov:entity>
    *************************
```

It throws error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-COMPARE: (err:XPTY0004) $i/descendant::prov:type = "assetTypeDescription" -- Items not comparable: xs:QName("foaf:OnlineAccount") = "assetTypeDescription"
```

Comment: You can’t compare a QName to a string. You probably mean for the right hand side to be a proper QName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the first `prov:type` element in the doc has a declared schema type:

```
<prov:type xsi:type="xsd:QName" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">foaf:OnlineAccount</prov:type>
```

When there are schema types for items (either through explicit `xsi:type` attribute, or when schemas are loaded into the Schemas database), then the code evaluates "schema aware" and knows what data type the elements and attributes are. This can change the behavior of the code. For instances like this, you don't necessarily get the automatic type coercion that you are expecting and instead it throws an error telling you that you can't compare `xs:QName` to a string.

If you want to treat the `prov:type` value as a string, then either remove the `@xsi:type` or change your `where` clause to eplicitly evaluate a string value:

```
where $i//prov:type/string() = 'assetTypeDescription'
```